# How can i make youtube put a certain type of music in my mix?

Tags: youtube, music

I have a youtube mix but its full of old songs i dont wanna listen to anymore over and over again so i cleaered them all out, now i want youtube to know i want shilo lofi, 21 pilots, and this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fL1pnzQj5j8&list=PL5jLvwlDs19FEva2AuQiqpg627BLuqvPg&index=2&t=0s recommended in my mix (not the whole playlist just some songs and similar songs like it) how do i do that? I tried watching a few videos of each and liking them but it didnt seem to change anything ):